# eigenvalue of differance between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A, B be two matrices is this relation true 
eigenvalue(A-B)= eigenvalue A - eigenvalue B where  A is matrices which all elements are 1 and B is the identity, A has an eigenvalue n with multiplicity 1 and o with multiplicity n-1, also I has eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity n

Answer (score 2):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if there exists a non trivial vector $v$ such that.

$Av = \lambda v$

Is $\lambda -1$ an eigenvalue of $A-I$?

$(A-I)v = Av - Iv = \lambda v - v = (\lambda - 1) v$

Comment: why you proof for $\lamda$-1 not for $\lamda$-n ?

Comment: @MaryamFasfous because that was the way your question was worded.  Certainly, it can be generalized to something more powerful.